# How to skip sting elements of lists in calculation?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to skip multiplication of string elements and float type. I want to avoid zero division error. So I try below codes.

```
x =[5,2,0.2,-2,1]
y=[4,3,2,1,0]
z=[m/n if m and n !=0 else "Na" for m,n in zip(x,y)]
print(z)
a=[i*0.5 if i != str else 0 for i in z]
print(a)
```

When I run above code. I got this results.

```
[1.25, 0.6666666666666666, 0.1, -2.0, 'Na']
Traceback (most recent call last):
a=[i*0.5 if i != str else 'Na' for i in z]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1enter code here
```

What I want to achieve is:
     a=[0.625,0.3333333333333333,0.05,-1.0,'Na']

Please point me out how I can do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `[i*0.5 if not isinstance(i, str) else 'Na' for i in s]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you are not doing type-checking correctly, as others have pointed out, to check the type of an instance you can use:

```
isinstance(str, x)
```

If you care about inheritance. `type(x) == str` or such comparisons also work, but do not take into account inheritance. But really, I believe the best solution is for you not to mix types. `float` already has a "not-a-number": `float('nan')`, so just use that:

```
>>> x =[5,2,0.2,-2,1]
>>> y=[4,3,2,1,0]
>>> z=[m/n if m and n !=0 else float('nan') for m,n in zip(x,y)]
>>> z
[1.25, 0.6666666666666666, 0.1, -2.0, nan]
>>> [i*0.5 for i in z]
[0.625, 0.3333333333333333, 0.05, -1.0, nan]
```

Then you don't have to worry about type-checking.

Then you can clean up later with `math.isnan`:

```
>>> [0 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in a]
[0.625, 0.3333333333333333, 0.05, -1.0, 0]
```

Or this trick, taking advantage of the guarantee that for any `float` `x`, `x != x` only if x is `nan`:

```
>>> [0 if x != x else x for x in a]
[0.625, 0.3333333333333333, 0.05, -1.0, 0]
```

But `math.isnan` is more explicit...

Answer (score 0):

in the following code

```
a=[i*0.5 if i != str else 0 for i in z]
```

you are checking `i` with type `str`, what you should do is check type of `i` with `str` like below

```
type(i) != str
```

Comment: you can use isinstance

Comment: yea, we can also do that.